# OpenCSV fields with commas

Tags: java, opencsv

I am creating a csv where fields may include commas. In java the writing is done with opencsv.

```
try (Writer fileWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(filePath))) {

      CSVWriter csvWriter =
          new CSVWriter(
              fileWriter,
              ICSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR,
              ICSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER,
              ICSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,
              ICSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END);
      csvWriter.writeNext(headers);
      csvWriter.writeAll(rows);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new IOException(e);
    }
```

So taking field like `["field, 1", "field, 2", "field, 3"]` I would expect to get a column with `"field, 1", "field, 2", "field, 3"` but I am getting `field", 1,field", 2,field", 3` .

In the actual the commas are gone when opening in excel and for expected the quotes would not be shown. I am not seeing any docs for this on opencsv.

Comment: I have no experience with opencsv, but this one talks to me  - `ICSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks good except the `ICSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER`. By passing `NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER` as the parameter you are asking OpenCSV to consider quotes as regular text in the file and that is what it is doing.

If you are confident that double quotes are going to be your quote character, you can change it to `ICSVWriter.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER`

Finally your snippet looks like below:

```
try (Writer fileWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(filePath))) {

  CSVWriter csvWriter =
      new CSVWriter(
          fileWriter,
          ICSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR,
          ICSVWriter.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER,
          ICSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,
          ICSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END);
  csvWriter.writeNext(headers);
  csvWriter.writeAll(rows);
} catch (IOException e) {
  throw new IOException(e);
}
```